# prove that the following series ($\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^2e^{-nx}$) defines differentiable function on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

prove that the following series defines differentiable function on $(0,\infty)$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^2e^{-nx}$$
I tried to show:

1) $f_n(x)=x^2e^{-nx}$ is differentiable -simple.

2) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^2e^{-nx}$ convergent for one point- also simple (for instance $x=1$).

3)$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (f_n(x))'$ uniformly convergent.

I got stuck on 3). I'm  was thinking about using M-test, but failed to find a series which is bigger than then this. I tried to find maximum to $(f_n(x))'$ and failed as well.

Comment: What do you mean by $\displaystyle \sum_{n = x}^\infty$?  do you really want $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty$? or something like that?

Comment: yes, sorry. one mistake many copies :)

Comment: use that $$\sum_{n=x}^\infty x^2e^{-nx}=\frac{x^2e^{x-x^2}}{e^x-1}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I need to show uniformly convergent for  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$ to use this sum?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

You prove it is differentiable at $[a,+\infty) $ for arbitrary $a>0$.

then it will be differentiable at $(0,+\infty) $.

$$f'_n (x) =x (2-nx)e^{-nx} $$

the max is attained at $x=a$ since for large enough $n $, we have
$$0 <2/n <a .$$

Comment: why differentiable  $[a, \infty)$ implements to open interval  $(0, \infty)$?

Comment: @Y.ofir For each $x>0$, there exists $a $ such that $0 <a <x $.